# wordpress custom query the events calendar

Tags: wordpress, events, calendar

I have 2 events in the 'u5' events category. Result shows as follow:

U5 vs Eagan
no events

How can i only show the event without the "no events" output?

```
date_default_timezone_set( 'America/Chicago' );
$today = date('j M Y');
$tomorrow = date('j M Y', strtotime('+1 days'));
$third = date('j M Y', strtotime('+2 days'));
$fourth = date('j M Y', strtotime('+3 days'));
$end_date = date('j M Y', strtotime('+4 days'));

global $post;
$upcoming = tribe_get_events(array('start_date'=>$today,'end_date'=>$end_date,'tribe_events_cat'=>'u5'));

if (count($upcoming) == 0) {
    echo '<li>No Events</li>';
} else {
    foreach($upcoming as $post) {
        setup_postdata($post);
        $start = tribe_get_start_date(null, false, 'j M Y');

        if($start == $tomorrow) {
            echo the_title();
        } else {
            echo 'no events';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have rewritten this as a function to make it reusable and to produce similar output to the example given. Pass the start date and number of days, expand the array as needed for additional groups.

```
function list_events( $start_date , $days ){
    date_default_timezone_set( 'America/Chicago' );
    global $post;
    $column_classes = array( 'first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth', 'seventh' );
    $start = strtotime( $start_date );
    for ( $i=0; $i<$days; $i++ ){
        $day = $start+86400*$i;
        $day_f=date( 'Y-m-d', $day );
        echo '<li class="'.$column_classes[$i].'">';
        echo '<span class="title">'.date('M j', $day).'</span>';
        $upcoming = tribe_get_events( array( 'eventDisplay'=>'all',  'start_date'=>$day_f,'end_date'=>$day_f.' 23:59:59' ) );
        if ( count( $upcoming ) == 0 ){
            echo '<span>No Events</span>';
        }else{
        foreach ( $upcoming as $post ){
            setup_postdata($post);
            echo '<span><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></span>';
            }
        }
        echo '</li>';
    }
    wp_reset_query();
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot Bryan, 

Thats heading in the right direction. How would I program it to say:

if todays date, show todays event
if tomorrows date, show tomorrows event
and so forth...

I realize it can be done manually, by setting up an if-statement to check for each day but it seems trivial. And i know there has to be an easier way. Here's a link to better understand http://www.futsalacademy.com/the-teams/development-program/u-5/